# Upgrade OS on multiple machines without network connection or peripherals

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I have many machines that are currently running Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to upgrade them to 16.04 in the fastest way possible. None of the machines are connected to a network (other than groups of machines are connected together) and none have peripherals connected to them. I am looking to do this without the need of connecting a monitor or keyboard to each individual machine every time I want to upgrade them. So far, I have been unsuccessful in finding any answers online other than manually booting from disk with a thumb drive inserted on each machine. If there are any other options in order to streamline this process, I would appreciate any ideas. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could do something like an [apt-cacher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server) server?

Comment: You might look at Clonezilla Server. Setup on your laptop, and connected to the local LAN segment, you can PXE boot the clients and restore an image.